# Как сделать бота тг на aiograme?

Tags: python, aiogram

Есть бот который работает, но есть функция(в другом файле и вызывается импортом ) которая парсит сайт и выводит через return значения.

и казало бы все прекрасно но когда идет выполнение этой функции бот не работает (точнее он работает скидывает инфу но кнопки не работают )

мне нужно соблюдать порядок выполнение функций в другом файле а асинхронные функции это нарушают.
или я что то не понимаю

Comment: Что вы от нас хотите? Чтобы мы волшебным образом поняли что у вас не так?

Comment: что именно не понятно?  Мне просто интересно как сделать так чтобы работал и бот и при этом он парсил сайт

Comment: Сделать парсер асинхронным?

Comment: ладно встречный вопрос как сделать парсер асинхронным чтобы он соблюдал порядок выполнения функций?

Comment: переписать его на `aiohttp`